# How to build nodejs application with vitejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, vite, monorepo, esbuild

my typescript application has 2 parts in a monorepo:

- a frontend in react, built with vitejs
- a backend with fastify, built with tsup

I want to use only one builder: vitejs with esbuild.
I find many things related with the use of vitejs with nodejs, but nothing works. :-(

do you have a sample project that build a nodejs application with vitejs ?